# Vertices on new objects arent aligned to axis properly

Tags: objects, vertices

When I add a new object into blender, for some reason there are a few vertices that arent aligning properly to the axis. For example when I add a cylinder, the far left vertex that is supposed to be at 0" on the Y but is showing .000004" off and the bottom vertex is supposed to be at 0" but is showing .000001" off.

I noticed it was doing this about halfway through a project yesterday when I noticed it was affecting several other things like the armatures. Is this a setting Ive changed or something? I cant find anything online and I cant rig anything correctly with it doing this.[image]

Comment: Hello :). These look like floating point rounding errors. You get around 7 decimal digits precision which is enough in most cases. There isn't much one can do about it, except switch to some CAD ready software.

Comment: Happens all the time, but the error is so extremely tiny that I have yet to see any real problem from it.

Comment: Thank you both. I hadnt noticed it before thinking it would be exact but if it doesnt cause any issues, Ill live. It is annoying though.

Comment: Also at play here, re screenshot, is rotation default unit is radians.  The default screen unit setting is to display in property box  as degrees.  2*pi radians = 360 degrees.  (amplifying the precision error)